# SNES Graphics Editor for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, software-recommendation, graphics, image-editing

Does anyone know of an editor than can open/read SNES 4BPP graphics files? Or at least one that can convert to/from this format?

Comment: Can you provide more information, please? What exactly does SNES stand for? Might you be referring to the Super Nintendo Entertainment System, for instance? Do you have some of these files available to examine?

Comment: @WheatWilliams: Yes, SNES means Super Nintendo Entertainment System. The files are just .bin (binary) files that are uncompressed SNES 4BPP tile data. If you want, here's a sample file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2298862/GFX00.bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNESTile is a Java-based cross-platform tool for editing SNES graphics.

Links:

- [GitHub Project](https://github.com/assemblr/SNESTile)
- [Mac Binary Download](http://imjake9.tk/download/SNESTile/app.zip/0.7)

Most such tools are DOS-based though. You could certainly download [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com) and some of the tools listed [here](http://www.zophar.net/utilities/snesgraph.html).

Comment: What's hilarious is that this is actually my project. I made it after finding that no suitable tool existed. Anyway, this is technically correct, so +1 and accept for you!

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with graphics from the SNES, but I would suggest that you investigate the commercial program

### [GraphicConverter](http://www.lemkesoft.com/content/143/import-and-export-formats.html)

which can read and write and convert more different graphic image formats than any other program of which I am aware.

You can download a free trial.

Comment: Sadly, that page doesn’t list BIN or 4BPP files explicitly — but it’s worth a shot, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no Mac app that can handle SNES graphics files.

But, if you use [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) to emulate DOS on OS X, check out [Naga](http://www.romhacking.net/utilities/101/), a DOS-based tile editor for NES, SNES, 8*X and 16*X games.